# importing variable from module in python makes copy?

Tags: python

It seems like doing `from foo import i` makes a copy of i rather than importing i into the current namespace.  Is that possible?

foo.py:

```
i=0
```

bar.py:

```
import foo
from foo import i

foo.i = 999

print i
print foo.i
```

This prints:

```
0
999
```

but I expected it them both to be 999 (just aliases for the same memory as it were).  What am I missing?

Comment: `i` and `foo.i` refer to the same object... but assigning to `foo.i` makes `foo.i` refer somewhere else, rather than going into the integer object and screwing with its value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> just aliases for the same memory as it were

You misunderstood how "variables" work in python. Variables are **not** memory locations. They are just *names* attached to objects. When you perform the assignment:

```
i = 0
```

you are giving the name `i` to a *new* object `0` *in the current scope*.

You should read the documentation about [naming and binding](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

---

Maybe a diagram can make this clearer:

Situations before modifying `i`:

```
foo.i       i
  |        /
  |       /
  |      /
  |     /
  |    /
  |   /
  |  /
+-----+
| 999 |
+-----+
```

The object `999` has two *references*. When you do:

```
i = 0
```

This is what happens:

```
foo.i         i
  |           |
  |           |
  |           |
  |           |
  |           |
  |           |
  |           |
+-----+     +---+
| 999 |     | 0 |
+-----+     +---+
```

If you want to modify the value of the `999` object... well: you **can't** because in python integers are **immutable**.

Note that it *doesn't* have to do with scopes:

```
i = 999
j = i
i = 0
print(i, j)  # prints: 0 999
```

The names `i` and `j` are just *labels* to objects. If you come from C you may think of *every* python variable as a *pointer* to the actual object. As if the above code was:

```
int *i = &999;
int *j = i;
i = &0;
printf("%d %d", *i, *j);
```

Comment: I do come from C, you're right.  I assumed that before modifying i, foo.i and i essentially point to the same memory (which they do I think).  But even if I write a setter in the foo module it doesn't work -- and not in the way I'd expect.  If I have a setter `def set_i(ii): global i; i=ii` in foo, and call that (from anywhere), I'd expect both foo.i and i to change in bar, or else neither of them.  But in fact foo.i changes and i doesn't.  It's like the name foo.i is changed to point to the new value, but the name i (which is imported from foo) doesn't change.

Comment: @GaryO That's the symmetric case. The fact that `i` is imported from `foo` does *not* create *any* relationship between the value of `foo.i` and `i`. In the case of using `set_i` you have: `int *i=&999; int *j=i; i = ii;` If you run this code in C you will see that `j` still points to `999`. It's perfectly symmetric. You just *cannot* perform an assignment in a scope and make it affect other existing scopes.

Comment: I guess this is what throws me: "The fact that i is imported from foo does not create any relationship between the value of foo.i and i."  I expected (incorrectly) that `from foo import i` would make `i` another way of spelling `foo.i`.  (Of course I see that if I made the value of foo.i a mutable type this would all work as I want.  I could just change the value in the container.)  Thanks for the interesting lesson!

Comment: And of course, a workaround for this is modifying a mutable object; e.g. use a dict and change its contents. But sharing variables in this way is usually a sign of bad design in python, so think twice if you really need this!

Comment: @GaryO "The fact that i is imported from foo does not create any relationship between the value of foo.i and i." actually, it does. foo.i and i both *reference* the same object (of type "int" with the value 999). It is just that by assigning i a new value, you break the reference because what you consider a scalar value is in fact a new object of type int with value 0. So foo.i and i end up pointing to different objects.

Comment: @miraculixx You misunderstood what I meant. My point is that *names are independent*. Performing an assignment on `i` does not change the object referred to by `foo.i` independently by the fact that they reference the same object or not.

Comment: @Bakuriu no, I did not misunderstand you. If you read my comment you see that I made the same point as you did but in different words.

Comment: @miraculixx You are right. I thought I worded it differently. In particular I didn't mean to put the `the value` in there.

Comment: So just to finish this up, if I want `i` to just be "shorthand" for `foo.i`, is the most pythonic solution to make `foo.i` be a function `foo.i()` which returns the internal variable?  Then `i()` and `foo.i()` can't get out of sync.  (The alternative is to use a dict or list, which might make sense if I have many `i` variants, `j`, `k` etc.)

Comment: @GaryO I believe that using some getter/setter function might probably be the best alternative. In fact this is used even by the stdlib of python (see, for example: [`sys.getrecursionlimit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit), [`sys.getprofile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getprofile) etc.) However in some circumstances you might realize that you actually want to write a class instead of having a module with shared state between functions.