# List remains unaltered even after commiting a swap function in python

Tags: python, function

I am a newbie to python so just a simple question about how python functions work since I am accustomed to C/C++ so here is my problem that I have a list:

```
a = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
```

and I have a function which takes two elements of list and swap them:

```
def swap(d,e):
    temp = e
    e = d
    d = temp
```

now when I pass it arguments like suppose

```
swap(a[0],a[5])
```

it doesn't do anything I mean list remains unaltered.Also I have defined my function at the very begining of the py file so also when I insert print temp like

```
def swap(d,e):
    temp = e
    print temp
    e = d
    d = temp
```

it gives me correct value say what a[5] is 
I mean if I have done anything like this in C

Comment: Shouldn't be surprising for you, coming from C/C++. Imagine that you write the exact same thing in C, making `a` a `char *`, and `void swap(char d, char e)`. Would you expect a change?

Comment: This wouldn't have worked in C or C++, either (though C++ would have let you declare the arguments as references, which would have worked).

Comment: You might wanna read: [How do I write a function with output parameters (call by reference)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: Since you are used to C: think of *every* variable as a pointer to the actual object. You might also be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21390975/510937) question about `import`s, since they are *not* the same as C's `include`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign `temp` to `e`, you're just creating a new reference to the object `e`, but what you take, has nothing to do with *the list*.

```
def swap(l, o, n): #pass the list, old position, new position
    l[n], l[o] = l[o], l[n]
```

This way, you do change the list.

Comment: I have assigned e as a[5] so anything I perform on e must reflect on a[5] so what is exactly happening

Comment: @saurabh Umm.. Not exactly like that. As jonrsharpe mentioned, they are bound _locally_ to `d` and `e`. When you assigned `e` to `a[5]`, you created a _new_ reference. Thus, changing `a[5]` _will_ change the value of `e`, but not the inverse. Reassigning `e` will only make it point to another object. AFAIK, it's not exactly like that in C either.

Comment: @saurabh: you're familiar with C. So let's say you write `char *a = "hello"; char *d = &a[0]; char *e = &a[5]; char *tmp = d; d = e; e = tmp;`. Would you say, "I have assigned `e` as `a[5]`, so anything I perform on `e` must reflect on `a[5]`"? If you would say that, then you are mistaken about C :-) Python variables are references to objects, they are not the referenced object.

Comment: @alKid I might have mistaken something but your answer and explaination does helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the objects from the list to `swap`, they are bound locally to the argument names `d` and `e`. You then swap `d` with `e` but that doesn't change the list. You could `return` the values:

```
def swap(d, e):
    return e, d
```

Then call it like:

```
a[0], a[5] = swap(a[0], a[5])
```

But clearly you might as well just do:

```
a[0], a[5] = a[5], a[0]
```

Alternatively, pass the list and indices, per alKid's answer.